# JQuery datatable custom pagination pagination resets on sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

We have .net MVC application in which using JQuery datatable. Implemented server side loading for datatable. the datatable is initialized as

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
    "searching": true,
    "pageLength": 1,
    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
    "serverSide": true, // for process server side
    "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
    "ajax": {
        "url": "Users/GetUsers",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "FirstName", "name": "FirstName"},
        { "data": "LastName", "name": "LastName" } 
    ]
});
```

And the controllers action is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUsers()
{
    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
    var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
    var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
    var searchstring = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();

    //Find Order Column
    var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

    int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    int recordsTotal = 0;

    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    // Logic to fetch users
    recordsTotal = users.Count();
    var data = users.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

In this case, the pagination works fine, but when we sort column (by clicking on datatable header row) the pagination resets to 1.

Ex if User is at page number 3, and click on header column to sort then the items are sorting but page number set back to 1, however it should be 3 only.

Can you please guide how can we avoid changing page number on sorting?

Thank You!

Comment: What is the value you get for 'start'?

Comment: If I am on page 3 then I itial load start value is 3 but after clicking on column for sort, it's coming as 0.

Comment: By clicking on a 'sort' column, you are generating a new result set, so it should go back to the start (page 1) - and that is the default